# Inequality for the trace of the hat matrix in Ridge regression

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, regression, trace

I was recently reviewing a research paper and came across an inequality expressed as follows:
\begin{align}
& \text{tr}\Big[\Big(\frac{1}{np}X^\top X + \rho B\Big)^{-1} \Big(\frac{1}{np}X^\top X\Big) \Big(\frac{1}{np}X^\top X + \rho B\Big)^{-1} \Big(\frac{1}{np}X^\top X\Big)\Big] \\
\leq & \text{tr}\Big[\Big(\frac{1}{np}X^\top X + \rho B\Big)^{-1} \Big(\frac{1}{np}X^\top X\Big)\Big] \tag{1},
\end{align}
where $X_{n\times p}$ is a design matrix, $\rho>0$ is a tuning parameter, and $B_{p\times p}$ is a positive definite matrix.

From my perspective, considering that $(\frac{1}{np}X^\top X + \rho B)^{-1}$ is positive definite (PD) and $X^\top X$ is positive semidefinite (PSD), we can simplify the expression as:
\begin{align*}
& \text{tr}\Big[\Big(\frac{1}{np}X^\top X + \rho B\Big)^{-1} \Big(\frac{1}{np}X^\top X\Big) \Big(\frac{1}{np}X^\top X + \rho B\Big)^{-1} \Big(\frac{1}{np}X^\top X\Big)\Big] \\
\leq & \text{tr}\Big[\Big(\frac{1}{np}X^\top X + \rho B\Big)^{-1} \Big(\frac{1}{np}X^\top X\Big)\Big] \; \text{tr}\Big[\Big(\frac{1}{np}X^\top X + \rho B\Big)^{-1} \Big(\frac{1}{np}X^\top X\Big)\Big].
\end{align*}
Now, if we can establish the inequality:
\begin{equation}
\text{tr}\Big[\Big(\frac{1}{np}X^\top X + \rho B\Big)^{-1} \Big(\frac{1}{np}X^\top X\Big)\Big] \leq 1 \tag{2},
\end{equation}
we can obtain the desired result. However, this may seem counterintuitive, as proving equation (2) directly implies that the original trace equation is less than or equal to 1.

I appreciate any insights or input on this matter. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to show $$Tr[(A+B)^{-1}A(A+B)^{-1}A] \leq Tr[(A+B)^{-1}A]
$$
where
$A$ is positive semi-definite and
$B$ is positive definite.

Since $A\leq A+B$ we have $(A+B)^{-1/2}A(A+B)^{-1/2} \leq I_p$. Letting
$C = (A+B)^{-1/2}A(A+B)^{-1/2}$, we obtain as a consequence  $C^{1/2} C C^{1/2} \leq C^{1/2}C^{1/2}$, i.e., $C^2\leq C$ which rewrites

$$(A+B)^{-1/2}A(A+B)^{-1}A(A+B)^{-1/2} \leq (A+B)^{-1/2}A(A+B)^{-1/2}.$$
Taking the trace and leveraging the cyclic property on each side yields
$$Tr[(A+B)^{-1}A(A+B)^{-1}A] \leq Tr[(A+B)^{-1}A].$$